# Kentico Display webpart property field depending on other property field's value

Tags: kentico

Is there anyway I can dynamically hide and display webpart property fields depending on other fields for the same webpart?

For example I only want to display/enable Full Screen if Apply To's selected value is "container":

[image]

I tried doing this but it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done.  On the property you are checking (ApplyTo) make sure you have checked the "Has depending fields" property checked.  On the property you want to toggle the visibility on, in the Visibility condition field, enter:

`ApplyTo.Value == "container"`

And also make sure it has the "Depends on another field" checked.

This will dynamically hide/show the field based on the value you have in the ApplyTo property.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow as below

1.Go to on Apply-To property in web-part then set 'Has depending fields' is checked.

2.Go to on full-width property in web-part then set Visibility condition: ApplyTo=='container'

you can also check this
https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-dependency-fields-in-forms

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about forms you can do it - there is a good tutorial: [Using dependency fields in forms](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-dependency-fields-in-forms)